# Can I warm up a DVD while paused if it spins down

Tags: vlc-media-player, dvd

When I pause a DVD in VLC, and walk away for a while (say, an hour or more), the DVD stops spinning. However, when I come back and hit play, VLC does not wait for the DVD to start spinning again. Instead, I have to reopen the DVD, choose play in the DVD menu, and seek to the correct spot where I stopped watching.

I'm running Windows 10. Is there a way to fix this?

- Can I run a command to warm up the DVD when I come back to it before hitting play in VLC?
- Can I tell VLC to be more patient when waiting for the DVD to spin up? (It does appear to wait for about a second.)
- Something else?

Comment: What happens if you open the DVD in your file manager, spinning it up, then press play? Presumably just the head seek is faster than a spin up & head seek. Might be worth asking VLC directly about this as it sounds like an issue with VLC.

Comment: This a question suited for the VLC forums.